# Show the diagonal is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset \Bbb R$ and we set $D\subset \Bbb R^2$ by $D = \{ {(x, x) : x\in A}\}.$  Show that $D$ is Lebesgue measurable calculate it measure $m(D)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", "Show", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Isn't $D$ just a subset of a line segment, which has planar Lebesgue measure zero. Indeed, it even has planar Jordan content zero (take infimum of sums of finite open coverings rather than infimum of sums of countable open coverings). Or am I missing something, or you've left something out?

Answer (score 2):

Let us show that $m(\bar{D}) = 0$ when $\bar{D} =  \{{(x, x) : x\in \mathbb{R}\}}$, then as $D \subseteq \bar{D}$ and $m(\bar{D})=0$ we have that $m(D) = 0$ and so $D$ is measurable.

Notice that:
$$m(\bar{D}) = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^2} \chi_{\bar{D}} \, dm = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \underbrace{ \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{\bar{D}}(x,y) \, dx} _{\star} \, dy
$$

But $\star = 0$ because when we hold $\tilde{y}$ as a constant, we have that:
$$\chi_{\bar{D}} (x,\tilde{y}) = \begin{cases} 
1 & x =\tilde{y} \\
0 & x \neq \tilde{y} \\
\end{cases} \implies \chi_{\bar{D}} (x,\tilde{y}) = 0 \; a.e. \implies \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{\bar{D}}(x,\tilde{y}) \, dx = 0 \implies m(\bar{D}) = 0$$
q.e.d.